# X and Y Coordinates are not plotted correctly despite correct CRS

Tags: qgis, xy

I have converted a layer from MSSQL to X and Y points through QGIS geoalgorithms -> vector creation tools -> points layer from table. I set my target CRS as EPSG: 4326 (UK) but it does not plot it in the correct spot. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: 4326 is lat/lon - 27700 is UK

Comment: omg. But i cant find 27700 in QGIS. I am using the 2.18.13 version.

Comment: *27700* - five digits

Comment: Apologies for the typo. Yes 27700. I cant seem to find it in the CRS.

Comment: it's there for me in 2.18.13 - just type 27700 in the CRS filter box - OSGB 1936 / British National Grid +proj=tmerc +lat_0=49 +lon_0=-2 +k=0.9996012717 +x_0=400000 +y_0=-100000 +ellps=airy +towgs84=446.448,-125.157,542.06,0.15,0.247,0.842,-20.489 +units=m +no_defs

Answer (score 1):

If your data is in the UK and doesn't have small numbers as coordinates then it is almost certainly in [EPSG:27700](http://epsg.io/27700) (OSGB National Grid) rather than [EPSG:4326](http://espg.io/4326) (Lat/Lon).